# Approach to group multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, group-by

I have tables title, studios, artists and tracks.

I am trying to extract title from title table, name of studio from studios table, name of the artist from artists table and number of tracks of the title from tracks table.

I have joined three tables and extracted the data from them using the below query.[image]

And then to get the count of number of tracks of each associated title I used the below query:

```
select t.title,s.studioname,a.artistname,count(tracks.titleid) as NumOfTracks 
from titles t, studios s, artists a,tracks where (t.studioid = s.studioid) and (t.artistid = a.artistid) and (tracks.titleid = t.titleid) 
group by t.title,s.studioname,a.artistname,tracks.titleid;
```

[image]

My query is whether this approach is the right way to group and extract data from multiple tables or is their any flaw in the above query?? I would appreciate your inputs.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach seems right (EDIT: As noted in the comment, except for `tracks.titleid` in the `group by` clause), although implicit joins (i.e., having several tables in the `from` clause) have been deprecated for several years now. You should probably be using explicit joins:

```
SELECT   t.title, 
         s.studioname,
         a.artistname,
         COUNT(tracks.titleid) as NumOfTracks 
FROM     titles t
JOIN     studios s ON t.studioid = s.studioid
JOIN     artists a ON t.artistid = a.artistid
JOIN     tracks ON tracks.titleid = t.titleid
GROUP BY t.title, s.studioname, a.artistname;
```

Comment: I think you might need to exclude tracks.titleid from GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @user2793228 on second look - yes. Got too wrapped up in the OP's query to notice. Edited and fixed. Thanks!